# Merge Sort divided by 4 - Time complexity of the pseudo code

Tags: sorting, merge, time-complexity, mergesort, pseudocode

I need to write a pseudo code for a Merge Sort (divided by 4), and figure out it's time complexity (And it must be in time complexity of Nlog(n) obviously).

This is what I wrote:

```
    Mergesort4(A){
    If   (n <= 1 ) return (A) 
    if (n=0) return(infinity) (Big number)

    k = (n/4)  m=(2n/4)  z=(3n/4)
    Return Merge4(Mergesort4(A[0..k-1]), Mergesort4(A[k..m-1]), 
                 Mergesort4(A[m..z-1]), Mergesort4(A[z..n-1), A[0..n-1])
    }
```

Merge4 - Divides B,C,D,R arrays into X.

Merge function merges 2 arrays, and creating a new array for the sorted elements.
(the Merge function is just like in the 2-way Merge sort)

```
Merge4(B,C,D,R,X){
          Merge(B,C,E)
          Merge(D,R,T)
          Merge(E,T,X)
}
```

The Time complexity is where I get confused.

Obviously, T(n)=4T(n/4)  (divides into 4 problems)

But I'm not sure what happens after the division.

My best guess would be: T(n)=4T(n/4) + O(n)

Guidelines would be appreciated...

Comment: The O(n) comes from the merge step, which remains basically the same. So, yes, the term is O(n) and your recurrence is the right one. You will find the recursion tree has O(log n) levels and does O(n) work at each level for O(n log n) total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, the final answer:

```
Mergesort4(A,p,r)
    If(q < r)
        q = floor( (p+r)/4 )
        Mergesort4(A, p, q)
        Mergesort4(A, q+1, 2q)
        Mergesort4(A, 2q+1, 3q)
        Mergesort4(A, 3q+1, r)
        Merge( A, p, q, q+1, 2q, 2q+1, 3q, 3q+1, r)


Merge( A, p, q, q+1, 2q, 2q+1, 3q, 3q+1, r )

    if(q != 0 && p != 0)
        Merge(A,p,q,2q)
    Merge(A,2q+1,3q,r)
    Merge(A,p,2q+1,r)
```